# How to remove borders

Tags: cropmarks

I have a latex template which, for some reason, displays the following border on each edge of each page:

[image: borders]

These borders still appear in the resulting pdf. Is there any way to remove them?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It's really hard to say what to do without more information. What kind of template? They really do look like printers' crop marks, as @ChristianHupfer alludes to below. Especially if the one you showed is in the upper left corner, and the others are like it, but rotated.

Comment: Is there some kind of `\usepackage{showframe}` active? or `crop`?

Comment: Crop marks is probably a correct diagnosis - I can see there's a whole crop.sty stylesheet included. This is a conference template, so I'm wondering if this is deliberately done for some reason and that I should keep it that way... (?). Either way - would love to know how I can go about 'cropping' so that the marks are not visible. Thanks for the warm welcome btw!

Comment: Does this conference template come with its own class or style file? If so, it could be hidden in there. In any case, if you are submitting a paper to a conference it's probably best to just leave it the way it comes out. Or if the template is available on the net somewhere, maybe you could point us at it, so someone could take a look?